# How can I code a liquidity pool?

Tags: plutus, plutus-pioneer-program, liquidity-pools

I am really interested in how i can code a liquidity pool using Plutus.
What are the mechanics & the components I need to handle? Is there a specific pattern, skeleton to follow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a good starting point are the following links bc the question is fairly broad. Perhaps also take a look at existing Dexes that (plan to) open source their code.

- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CPfcyDaDtt8
- https://plutus-pioneer-program.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pioneer/week10.html